# Jquery slider if not working

Tags: jquery, text, slider

I trying to catch IF when my text is going left : 0px but it's not working :< For any tip i will be thankfully.

```
   <script src="_js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="_js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="_js/code.js"></script>

<div class="container-for-slider">
          <ul class="slides">
            <li  class="slide">Witam na stronie głównej</li>
            <li  class="slide">strona cały czas się rozwija</li>
            <li  class="slide">nowe pomysły nowe możliwości</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hqp0w778/1/

```
setInterval(function () {
       $('.container-for-slider .slides').animate({'left':'-=500px'}, 5000, function () {
         if($('.container-for-slider .slides').position().left == '0px'){
         alert('lol');
     }
     });
     }, 1000);
```

Comment: Please be more clear about what your code should do and how it is failing to do that

Answer (score 0):

Result of `$('.container-for-slider .slides').position().left` is an integer. Try this:

`if ($('.container-for-slider .slides').position().left == 0)`

I also notice when testing `.position().left` does not return 0 ever: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/hqp0w778/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.container-for-slider .slides').animate({
      'left': '-=300px'
    }, 5000, function() {
      console.log("Position:", $('.container-for-slider .slides').position().left);
      if ($('.container-for-slider .slides').position().left === 0) {
        alert('lol');
      }
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```